# ZMQ - Client Server: Client is powered off unexpectedly, how server detects it?

Tags: c++, client-server, zeromq

Multiple clients are connected to a single `ZMQ_PUSH` socket. When a client is powered off unexpectedly, server does not get an alert and keep sending messages to it. Despite of using `ZMQ_OBLOCK` and setting `ZMQ_HWM` to 5 (queue only 5 messages at max), my server doesn't get an error until unless client is reconnected and all the messages in queue are received at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently ran into a similar problem when using ZMQ. We would cut power to interconnected systems, and the subscriber would be unable to reconnect automatically. It turns out the there has recently (past year or so) been implemented a heartbeat mechanism over ZMTP, the underlying protocol used by ZMQ sockets.

If you are using ZMQ version 4.2.0 or greater, look into setting the ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_IVL and ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT socket options (http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-setsockopt). These will set the interval between heartbeats (ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_IVL) and how long to wait for the reply until closing the connection (ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT).

EDIT: You must set these socket options before connecting.

Comment: Thank you... I implemented a variant of Paranoid Pirate Pattern to send/receive heartbeat and that too solved my problem. :)

Comment: Just noticed your answer, and thank you for it! I'm out of date... That's very interesting, but there seems to be precious little in the zmq docs about it. Do you know if heartbeat timeout events are visible through zmq_poll? I vaguely recall that one can hook into connection events in some way.

Comment: Using zmq_poll() with the socket you care about won't give you this information by itself. However, it looks like you can use zmq_socket_monitor(http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket-monitor), then create a PAIR socket on the same endpoint, and finally add that PAIR socket to your poll items. I haven't tried this, but it looks like this technique would allow you to use zmq_poll() to monitor the connect/disconnect events (the disconnect events would happen when the heartbeat fails, I believe).

Comment: @MikeFoss, sorry for the slow reply, just noticed your comment. Thanks for that, that does indeed look like the very thing. It's a fair assumption that if the connection is timed out for a lack of a PING, that that would show up as a disconnect. I shall have to give it a go. With this available, one can do some quite powerful fail-over actions at the application level, which I've found remarkably useful in the past.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in zmq explicitly to detect the unexpected termination of a program at the other end of a socket, or the gratuitous and unexpected failure of a network connection.

There has been historical talk of adding some kind of underlying ping-pong are-you-still-alive internal messaging to zmq, but last time I looked (quite some time ago) it had been decided not to do this.

This does mean that crashes, network failures, etc aren't necessarily handled very cleanly, and your application will not necessarily know what is going on or whether messages have been successfully sent. It is Actor model after all. As you're finding your program may eventually determine something had previously gone wrong. Timeouts in zmtp will spot the failure, and eventually the consequences bubble back up to your program.

To do anything better you'd have to layer something like a ping-pong on top yourself (eg have a separate socket just for that so that you can track the reachability of clients) but that then starts making it very hard to use the nice parts of ZMQ such as push / pull. Which is probably why the (excellent) zmq authors decided not to put it in themselves.

When faced with a similar problem I ended up writing my own transport library. I couldn't find one off the shelf that gave nice behaviour in the face of network failures, crashes, etc. It implemented CSP, not actor model, wasn't terribly fast (an inevitability), didn't do patterns in the zmq sense, but did mean that programs knew exactly where messages were at all times, and knew that clients were alive or unreachable at all times. The CSPness also meant message transfers were an execution rendezvous, so programs know what each other is doing too.